# Get contacts information with authentication

Tags: integration

I want to know if there is a way for me to make an application in PHP or another language where somebody puts their username and password and I compare their contacts with my contacts to see which contacts are different in our accounts.

For example, his contacts are:

```
John Smith, VP, Coca Cola
Peter Smith, Manager, Pepsi
Mary Smith, President, Dr Pepper
```

And my contacts are

```
Steven Smith, President, Microsoft
Peter Smith, Manager, Pepsi
Raymond Smith, Manager, Coca Cola
```

At the end that analysis would give something like:

```
Accounts found: 1
Accounts not found: 2
```

(Because we both have Peter Smith)

Is this clear? Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what their contacts are, nor where you are saying someone puts in a username and password.

Comment: It would be on a form. Their contacts would be in Salesforce

Comment: Unless you're doing this frequently I'd recommend just using workbench.developerforce.com, download your contacts to csv, login as them, download theirs to csv, then use Excel to find or remove the dupes.

Comment: Do you mean 1 person can verify the contact details you have of them in salesforce ? Or a person can synchronize some amount of contact data they have with your stored contacts ? It may help if you update your question to do a more detailed description.

Comment: I edited it a little bit, please let me know if its clear

Comment: You wish to compare data of two users within Salesforce or with some table in another system (since you mention PHP)? And what really do you mean when you say 'His contacts','My contacts'.. is it record ownership?

Comment: Compare the contacts in my object "Contact" with the contacts in the object "Contact" of another user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use salesforce [REST API](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_REST_API) feature where you can send a request to salesforce. That request will contain the list of your contacts. Then you can compare those contact with the contacts in salesforce and return the http response according to your requirement.

Let me know if you didn't understand.